# Can the Angular Material ErrorStateMatcher detect when a parent form is submitted?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a parent component that sets up a form and passes it down to a child component.

```html
<form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="submit()">
  <app-child [form]="form"></app-child>
  <button mat-button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The child component displays an input field like this:

```html
<mat-form-field *ngIf="form" [formGroup]="form">
  <input matInput
         placeholder="Email"
         formControlName="email"
         [errorStateMatcher]="matcher"
         required>
</mat-form-field>
```

The input field is required and should show an error if the form is submitted without filling it in, even if the user never touched it. This is the automatic behavior in a simple form, but (I think) since I am using a child form, I have to implement custom error logic with `ErrorStateMatcher`.

```js
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control, form) {
    return control && control.invalid && form && form.submitted;
  }
}
```

However, this doesn't work. I can't figure out how to get the child input to detect when the parent form has been submitted. The `ErrorStateMatcher` detects that something has changed, but the `submitted` property of `form` is always `false`. What am I doing wrong?

[See this Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-error-matcher-child-component)

Comment: I ran into this exact same problem after following Angular's documentation on dynamic forms (https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form) and then modifying it to use Material. The answer by @ysf worked it for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to implement `ErrorStateMatcher` to achieve such behavior. and it doesn't make sense to use `formGroup` on a `mat-form-field`

Just change `child.component.html` as follows

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="form">
  <input matInput placeholder="Email" [formControl]="form.get('email')">
</mat-form-field>
```

here is a working example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-error-matcher-child-component-6nwmwe

Comment: For anyone else trying to implement this, make sure to change `formControlName` to `[formControl]` (and use `form.get` to get the actual control).

Comment: I've also noticed an issue when using `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` in my real-world app, though I can't reproduce that in StackBlitz.